# fix wrong calculation of cumulative histogram with facet_wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot cumulative histogram with ggplot for different groups of my data.
The code below gives me a wrong result (image at the bottom):

```
ggplot(df_cl,aes(x=gap,color=cluster)) +
  stat_bin(data=df_cl_first,aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="bar",bins = 50) + xlab("Gap time (Hours)")+ ylab("Counts") + ggtitle("The first transitions")+facet_wrap(~transitions)+ xlab("Gap time (hours)") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,  hjust=1))
```

However, using the code below, when I subset my data to only one group, it plots correctly (image below). I want all corrected plots.

```
ggplot(df_cl,aes(x=gap,color=cluster)) +
  stat_bin(data=subset(df_cl_first,transitions=="E-A",aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="bar",bins = 50) + xlab("Gap time (Hours)")+ ylab("Counts") + ggtitle("The first transitions")+facet_wrap(~transitions,scales = "free")+ xlab("Gap time (hours)") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,  hjust=1))
```

[image]

[image]

Here is dput of mydata (lets call df_cl_first)

```
structure(list(gap = c(7.78555555555555, 14.1686111111111, 27.5397222222222, 
120, 38.2436111111112, 80.8772222222222, 120, 120, 22.5333333333333, 
1.185, 22.8441666666667, 120, 17.2791666666667, 2.94722222222222, 
22.7172222222222, 4.87027777777778, 2.98861111111112, 37.1177777777778, 
120, 25.545, 57.8566666666667, 0.910833333333333, 51.6758333333333, 
120, 50.88, 24.1222222222222, 5.56611111111112, 21.0866666666667, 
6.68555555555555, 3.64694444444445, 120, 120, 21.3875, 18.3275, 
32.4083333333333, 5.33861111111112, 11.395, 94.4047222222222, 
72.2988888888888, 4.65888888888888, 28.3388888888888, 1.05361111111111, 
99.0541666666667, 48.3925, 120, 21.2772222222222, 2.14416666666667, 
55.6533333333333, 1.43055555555555, 28.1952777777778, 120, 25.8386111111112, 
8.27638888888888, 14.3791666666667, 0.509444444444445, 7.43138888888888, 
71.4875, 3.28916666666667, 2.23027777777778, 110.265277777778, 
11.6911111111111, 120, 120, 3.83888888888888, 53.8891666666667, 
26.5680555555555, 22.6980555555555, 2.04, 120, 97.7705555555555, 
21.9494444444445, 0.68, 69.7227777777778, 24.7188888888888, 1.36861111111111, 
25.5316666666667, 1.79305555555555, 5.92388888888888, 1.57694444444445, 
10.3308333333333, 120, 115.1275, 107.131666666667, 10.1436111111111, 
29.1388888888888, 41.3797222222222, 1.01805555555556, 3.66916666666667, 
24.9463888888888, 1.05361111111111, 0.6675, 24.4388888888888, 
0.841944444444445, 76.7022222222222, 0.6375, 18.4327777777778, 
17.1327777777778, 30.0577777777778, 20.6780555555555, 21.0130555555555, 
105.397777777778, 15.45, 120, 76.7008333333333, 2.90666666666667, 
17.4397222222222, 2.24972222222222, 14.84, 59.4061111111112, 
120, 1.41027777777778, 51.6802777777778, 36.04, 37.0169444444445, 
33.8286111111112, 23.6752777777778, 51.2194444444445, 1.62527777777778, 
22.3616666666667, 24.4883333333333, 20.1463888888888, 1.59138888888889, 
10.0438888888889, 12.4363888888889, 23.2297222222222, 0.432777777777778, 
2.04916666666667, 47.4180555555555, 22.8272222222222, 106.957222222222, 
120, 51.5816666666667, 24.52, 120, 86.8544444444445, 2.58583333333333, 
28.4222222222222, 78.5116666666667, 20.3133333333333, 19.3891666666667, 
24.0302777777778, 2.09583333333333, 120, 1.02888888888889, 120, 
91.1216666666667, 120, 120, 3.80361111111112, 12.5463888888889, 
1.31638888888889, 5.66, 120, 8.43194444444445, 52.7363888888888, 
0.971944444444445, 3.62777777777778, 15.1877777777778, 110.176388888889, 
30.7216666666667, 1.97444444444445, 14.3122222222222, 120, 24.0594444444445, 
7.74833333333333, 5.38694444444445, 17.7597222222222, 0.274166666666667, 
1.89694444444445, 15.5227777777778, 1.12333333333333, 0.00527777777777778, 
9.43416666666667, 24.4752777777778, 1.05083333333333, 17.2725, 
47.5886111111112, 21.8705555555555, 5.95305555555555, 62.9777777777778, 
120, 2.35777777777778, 2.08416666666667, 91.3930555555555, 24.75, 
25.6938888888888, 29.2877777777778, 120, 25.1313888888888, 120, 
27.1638888888888, 19.5155555555555, 2.15555555555555, 0.162777777777778, 
2.65333333333333, 27.6066666666667, 21.0719444444445, 73.6272222222222, 
3.07527777777778, 49.5472222222222, 44.7752777777778, 52.4397222222222, 
45.3258333333333, 10.2908333333333, 1.74527777777778, 18.9361111111112, 
5.06583333333333, 59.8630555555555, 1.49805555555556, 71.9805555555555, 
20.5783333333333, 1.23416666666667, 21.7186111111112, 2.62638888888888, 
44.7775, 92.6111111111112, 111.843055555556, 0.954722222222222, 
3.93194444444445, 17.6791666666667, 1.92277777777778, 4.50222222222222, 
95.1116666666667, 21.4383333333333, 3.43805555555555, 2.92944444444445, 
0.938611111111112, 106.055277777778, 1.40944444444445, 74.3505555555555, 
32.4861111111112, 21.7636111111112, 120, 10.4677777777778, 43.8511111111112, 
41.8969444444445, 16.5922222222222, 26.4997222222222, 26.4552777777778, 
11.2033333333333, 11.6183333333333, 101.805, 39.1130555555555, 
6.49305555555555, 15.9866666666667, 0.826111111111112, 1.08777777777778, 
66.5825, 21.8994444444445, 0.513611111111112, 2.53277777777778, 
13.8561111111111, 51.2755555555555, 0.207222222222222, 0.448333333333333, 
6.21055555555555, 1.49388888888889, 21.255, 97.8125, 26.0622222222222, 
120, 22.7002777777778, 20.3888888888888, 27.2111111111112, 4.33861111111112, 
0.112777777777778, 9.92694444444445, 11.2455555555555, 71.5258333333333, 
2.13638888888888, 120, 0.697222222222222, 4.05944444444445, 10.9269444444444, 
6.77, 17.9869444444445, 23.6219444444445, 0.254166666666667, 
4.02916666666667, 15.9519444444445, 63.7327777777778, 4.64111111111112, 
20.3013888888888, 96.095, 95.4272222222222, 76.28, 120, 27.3377777777778, 
43.0380555555555, 120, 28.7747222222222, 15.4836111111111, 95.3113888888888, 
3.17611111111112, 120, 1.63527777777778, 3.81694444444445, 44.8483333333333, 
87.1019444444445, 3.03416666666667, 17.9247222222222, 0.375555555555555, 
93.2572222222222, 72.6258333333333, 3.9725, 21.0969444444445, 
22.9544444444445, 47.9427777777778, 52.6508333333333, 17.485, 
4.54555555555555, 8.11083333333333, 15.2297222222222, 0.0661111111111112, 
15.7427777777778, 1.72972222222222, 55.5208333333333, 13.6641666666667, 
3.07111111111112, 16.2383333333333, 23.3136111111112, 120, 112.106666666667, 
1.30833333333333, 0.509166666666667, 24.2286111111112, 4.24888888888888, 
27.1758333333333, 120, 72.6772222222222, 5.43, 51.8019444444445, 
75.1944444444445, 66.4719444444445, 23.6202777777778, 25.3316666666667, 
88.8547222222222, 7.47944444444445, 120, 72.7666666666667, 91.2547222222222, 
68.6941666666667, 5.59972222222222, 13.3408333333333, 0.848055555555555, 
120, 26.0952777777778, 0.918333333333333, 16.2697222222222, 35.3266666666667, 
45.5922222222222, 68.8352777777778, 2.76083333333333, 50.3033333333333, 
0.215833333333333, 3.64666666666667, 56.0891666666667, 0.813333333333333, 
120, 0.514166666666667, 18.3063888888888, 1.08416666666667, 8.02305555555555, 
6.96222222222222, 7.87055555555555, 72.6011111111112, 23.7486111111112, 
5.78166666666667, 2.93555555555555, 2.91388888888888, 35.3208333333333, 
38.1072222222222, 2.27777777777778, 42.8758333333333, 6.57694444444445, 
36.2086111111112, 14.845, 23.6116666666667, 22.8280555555555, 
22.4355555555555, 2.29111111111112, 16.6669444444445, 24.6691666666667, 
99.5733333333333, 120, 31.7969444444445, 63.8486111111112, 25.2466666666667, 
75.0733333333333, 29.9866666666667, 113.969444444444, 0.581111111111112, 
17.5605555555555, 0.4225, 78.7369444444445, 21.7197222222222, 
15.8861111111111, 120, 27.0541666666667, 120, 31.1075, 89.0252777777778, 
30.7258333333333, 15.5080555555556, 21.5902777777778, 6.92138888888888, 
20.5125, 45.3772222222222, 44.9666666666667, 1.4525, 26.4663888888888, 
0.622777777777778, 16.6430555555556, 14.9925, 3.01444444444445, 
1.37416666666667, 20.8669444444445, 17.3466666666667, 30.1327777777778, 
78.9197222222222, 14.3236111111111, 45.4313888888888, 16.7686111111112, 
0.281111111111112, 5.82833333333333, 13.2405555555556, 2.305, 
119.249444444444, 3.59666666666667, 2.50972222222222, 15.0522222222222, 
77.64, 6.03333333333333, 16.0786111111111, 24.7305555555555, 
25.1511111111112, 120, 27.6475, 3.78138888888888, 46.0583333333333, 
120, 21.8677777777778, 0.344722222222222, 72.3397222222222, 25.9363888888888, 
4.30916666666667, 120, 0.366944444444445, 120, 2.7225, 2.12, 
1.48611111111111, 3.1025, 0.661944444444445, 23.1936111111112, 
85.9416666666667, 4.91805555555555, 22.4847222222222, 5.23666666666667, 
16.9719444444445, 46.0919444444445, 0.790833333333333, 22.8, 
4.38666666666667, 28.4880555555555, 65.7630555555555, 2.40305555555555, 
97.5841666666667, 46.6516666666667, 16.7727777777778, 75.5625, 
50.3697222222222, 17.2833333333333, 0.00416666666666667, 116.659444444445, 
23.1, 2.86111111111112, 4.00277777777778, 17.5291666666667, 0.665, 
95.8638888888888, 22.2972222222222, 4.52777777777778, 1.14722222222222, 
7.1975, 120, 120, 50.6269444444445, 5.96638888888888, 7.69722222222222, 
1.63583333333333, 75.3655555555555, 92.0019444444445, 48.2355555555555, 
1.24, 48.5502777777778, 2.96472222222222, 12.7108333333333, 5.11222222222222, 
120, 9.24361111111112, 120, 79.2333333333333, 53.3161111111112, 
4.47, 4.30777777777778, 26.8438888888888, 0.267222222222222, 
6.88333333333333, 116.6875, 2.91777777777778, 66.2772222222222, 
27.9552777777778, 120, 33.755, 26.8852777777778, 13.8425, 3.57416666666667, 
71.7, 11.3769444444445, 20.1411111111112, 17.2458333333333, 30.2197222222222, 
13.2491666666667, 1.4975, 32.9697222222222, 12.7161111111111, 
21.6116666666667, 88.5972222222222, 3.01083333333333, 22.3280555555555, 
22.1941666666667, 1.18222222222222, 71.4958333333333, 73.285, 
45.9372222222222, 76.0683333333333, 20.6325, 2.49027777777778, 
48.9338888888888, 23.9144444444445, 19.2508333333333, 99.8025, 
17.9513888888888, 94.6005555555555, 22.6805555555555, 24.0094444444445, 
5.215, 24.8005555555555, 65.6636111111112, 120, 46.2266666666667, 
83.4152777777778, 46.0658333333333, 20.4316666666667, 0.965833333333333, 
5.07666666666667, 0.699166666666667, 47.0636111111112, 98.09, 
3.88194444444445, 41.5725, 20.9466666666667, 1.29166666666667, 
7.56083333333333, 111.690555555555, 2.26666666666667, 2.07777777777778, 
24.5069444444445, 18.1372222222222, 3.78805555555555, 34.0133333333333, 
112.200277777778, 0.619444444444445, 0.326388888888888, 32.5541666666667, 
14.6547222222222, 1.56722222222222, 45.6736111111112, 22.64, 
98.3311111111112, 21.9433333333333, 23.0002777777778, 48.2711111111112, 
4.85416666666667, 0.501111111111112, 120, 21.9622222222222, 53.5413888888888, 
21.1538888888888, 5.185, 16.5166666666667, 13.1563888888889, 
3.59805555555555, 18.26, 9.76722222222222, 75.9, 9.83166666666667, 
1.39888888888889, 21.5172222222222, 72.45, 2.55472222222222, 
2.35222222222222, 93.8819444444445, 0.394722222222222, 0.516944444444445, 
2.33694444444445, 4.29583333333333, 1.62333333333333, 9.75166666666667, 
5.30305555555555, 33.7911111111112, 23.0111111111112, 1.03916666666667, 
1.24722222222222, 25.9677777777778, 120, 120, 74.8802777777778, 
39.8333333333333, 8.31666666666667, 66.7136111111112, 0.260833333333333, 
0.693055555555555, 34.4483333333333, 8.45527777777778, 120, 47.9644444444445, 
0.706666666666667, 41.9711111111112, 10.5897222222222, 11.1408333333333, 
62.9316666666667, 89.4213888888888, 30.9216666666667, 19.6725, 
20.22, 37.0872222222222, 37.5363888888888, 67.8258333333333, 
0.353333333333333, 29.2263888888888, 44.6897222222222, 6.46555555555555, 
94.1658333333333, 37.1052777777778, 95.2941666666667, 58.9925, 
50.1627777777778, 0.586111111111112, 7.28305555555555, 23.3019444444445, 
51.8141666666667, 4.58277777777778, 1.81916666666667, 12.5725, 
7.95944444444445, 120, 1.7475, 1.33027777777778, 22.8969444444445, 
73.7358333333333, 39.9275, 98.0780555555555, 0.2175, 15.4827777777778, 
5.05444444444445, 3.01166666666667, 18.6694444444445, 22.5469444444445, 
2.15916666666667, 42.565, 6.89638888888888, 21.3155555555555, 
12.8833333333333, 1.45861111111111, 6.39638888888888, 27.1363888888888, 
120, 0.3225, 0.937222222222222, 101.060833333333, 13.0325, 25.2763888888888, 
2.5525, 1.70416666666667, 2.93722222222222, 27.4822222222222, 
110.371388888889, 1.53083333333333, 42.1836111111112, 8.48222222222222, 
22.2694444444445, 0.0933333333333333, 0.183333333333333, 0.00194444444444445, 
120, 0.738333333333333, 120, 7.36666666666667, 2.55388888888888, 
12.7883333333333, 109.218055555556, 2.70694444444445, 3.49111111111112, 
38.3666666666667, 2.80416666666667, 98.9605555555555, 1.7175, 
97.8955555555555, 1.17861111111111, 0.0747222222222222, 16.6591666666667, 
120, 13.3208333333333, 2.23222222222222, 2.165, 18.9586111111112, 
3.52, 46.2111111111112, 120, 4.85833333333333, 1.54861111111111, 
120, 4.73888888888888, 120, 25.0486111111112, 10.8488888888889, 
11.4775, 1.68805555555555, 46.8458333333333, 60.7041666666667, 
27.6647222222222, 6.89805555555555, 4.78611111111112, 1.57277777777778, 
120, 2.11027777777778, 0.481111111111112, 1.91444444444445, 17.1616666666667, 
21.7877777777778, 3.3675, 120, 7.12138888888888, 25.3163888888888, 
3.9125, 3.96833333333333, 120, 20.1147222222222, 120, 28.8127777777778, 
15.5222222222222, 9.80527777777778, 24.2130555555555, 49.5613888888888, 
40.8461111111112, 0.978611111111112, 21.3977777777778, 56.3725, 
3.53611111111112, 13.345, 40.4516666666667, 81.5705555555555, 
120, 120, 0.845555555555555, 3.98055555555555, 1.02055555555555, 
1.82833333333333, 43.1036111111112, 3.54333333333333, 0.385, 
1.19, 120, 120, 22.3744444444445, 2.52388888888888, 21.2227777777778, 
2.42305555555555, 120, 94.2786111111112, 19.0808333333333, 27.6480555555555, 
6.21694444444445, 10.7322222222222, 13.5511111111111, 69.4702777777778, 
3.57111111111112, 0.357777777777778, 0.730833333333333, 2.30583333333333, 
1.19388888888889, 5.11944444444445, 4.57055555555555, 0.322222222222222, 
51.3030555555555, 12.9872222222222, 22.0208333333333, 120), transitions = structure(c(2L, 
7L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 
16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 
12L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 
7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
3L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
16L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 9L, 
3L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 
15L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 
1L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 
9L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 2L, 
7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 4L, 14L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 
7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 
16L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 13L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 
15L, 16L, 13L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 13L, 
2L, 8L, 15L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 
12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 
7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 3L, 12L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 
16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
16L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 8L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 
16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 
1L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 
7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
13L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
13L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 1L, 4L, 14L, 
7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 4L, 14L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 
7L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 11L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 
12L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 16L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 
2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 
16L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 
16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 
2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
11L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 16L, 15L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 16L, 1L, 
2L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 15L), .Label = c("D-D", "D-P", "D-E", "D-A", 
"P-D", "P-P", "P-E", "P-A", "E-D", "E-P", "E-E", "E-A", "A-D", 
"A-P", "A-E", "A-A"), class = "factor"), cluster = c("CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL1", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL1", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL1", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL1", "CL1", "CL1", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL1", "CL1", "CL1", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL1", "CL1", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL1", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL1", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL1", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL1", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL1", "CL2", 
"CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL2", "CL2", "CL2", "CL1", "CL1", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", "CL3", 
"CL3", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", 
"CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4", "CL4")), row.names = c(NA, 
-800L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to precalculate before ggplot:

```
library(dplyr)
df_cl %>%
  mutate(gap = floor(gap)) %>%
  count(transitions, cluster, gap) %>%
  tidyr::complete(transitions, cluster, gap, fill = list(n=0)) %>%
  group_by(cluster, transitions) %>%      # EDIT again
  mutate(counts_cuml = cumsum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x=gap,y=counts_cuml, fill=cluster)) +
  geom_area() +
  labs(x="Gap time (Hours)",
       y="Counts",
       title="The first transitions") +
  facet_wrap(~transitions) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,  hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but there is still a problem. There is only 1 count for P-D but it shows 200>. I think the problem is that it keeps increasing, and it does not sum based on group of transitions. So, the calculation of cumsum should be independent per transition.

Comment: Ah, I see, then I think we'd just need the edit I've just made. `group_by(cluster) %>%` should be `group_by(cluster, transition) %>%`

Comment: thanks, the trend is correct but numbers do not match when I plot separately. E-A should be 400> but it shows around 200.

Comment: [sorry mean `transitions` not `transition` above]

Comment: In the example data there are 155 rows in E-A, no?

Comment: thats correct. Thank you. By any chance, can my code (above) to be fixed to produce such result?